# Generate unique ID with Javascript from strings and numbers

Tags: javascript, html

How do you generate a unique ID consisting of the first letter of every first name, their whole last name and the last four digits of their ID? I'm still new to Javascript and so far I've never found anything that could generate based on strings and numbers that have already been input in a form. The strings and numbers originate from a signup form. What functions do I use? I hope anyone can guide me in this. Example of my form is:

```
<label><b>First Name</b></label><br>
<input type="string" placeholder="Ex. Anne Marie //capitalize every first letter" id="Fname" required><br>
```

Comment: Get the values from the form. Concatenate strings. Both things are easy to search for; I'd start there.

Comment: Could you give an example of first name, last name and ID and an example of what you want to create? Also, is this a randomised ID?

Comment: @DaveNewton values as in? Like the id?

Comment: @Zak First Name: Anne Marie, Last Name: James,  ID: 761114195280. It's not randomised.

Comment: And what should be generated?

Comment: @Zak amJames4280

Comment: But according to your description it should be `AJames5280` for `First Name: Anne Marie, Last Name: James, ID: 761114195280`.

Comment: @PankajShukla Actually it has to print out every first letter of the first name. Like Anne Marie so 'a' and 'm'.

Comment: @AmeeJay I've posted the answer for you, let me know if that help.

Comment: Don't try to grab everything at once. Find how to split string by words, then to take first chars, then go to uppercase etc. It's easy when you divide your problem in smaller pieces!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5tLrczje/1/

Html:

```
<label><b>First Name</b></label><br>
<input type="string" placeholder="Ex. Anne Marie // Capitalize every first letter" id="Fname" required><br>
<label><b>Last Name</b></label><br>
<input type="string" placeholder="Ex. Smith // Capitalize every first letter" id="Lname" required><br>
<label><b>ID</b></label><br>
<input type="string" placeholder="Ex. 123456 // Numbers only" id="ID" required><br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Get ID" onclick="getUniq()"><br><br>
<label><b>Result</b></label><br>
<input type="string" id="Result"><br><br>
```

Js:

```
getUniq = function() {
    var fn = document.getElementById('Fname').value;
    var ln = document.getElementById('Lname').value;
    var id = document.getElementById('ID').value;

    var result = "";

    var fn_arr = fn.split(/[ ]+/);
    for(var i in fn_arr)
        result = result + fn_arr[i].substr(0,1);

    result = result + ln;
    result = result + id.substr(-4);

    alert(result);
}
```

Here is a standalone HTML (you can ignore two pieces of code shown above):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<label><b>First Name</b></label><br>
<input type="string" placeholder="Ex. Anne Marie // Capitalize every first letter" id="Fname" required><br>
<label><b>Last Name</b></label><br>
<input type="string" placeholder="Ex. Smith // Capitalize every first letter" id="Lname" required><br>
<label><b>ID</b></label><br>
<input type="string" placeholder="Ex. 123456 // Numbers only" id="ID" required><br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Get ID" onclick="getUniq()"><br>

<script type="text/javascript">
    getUniq = function () {
        var fn = document.getElementById('Fname').value;
        var ln = document.getElementById('Lname').value;
        var id = document.getElementById('ID').value;

        var result = "";

        var fn_arr = fn.split(/[ ]+/);
        for (var i in fn_arr)
            result = result + fn_arr[i].substr(0, 1);

        result = result + ln;
        result = result + id.substr(-4);

        alert(result);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It didn't get any results. Do i have to add anything?

Comment: Can you navigate to the fiddle I created:
https://jsfiddle.net/5tLrczje/1/

After filling some data and after clicking "Get ID" you should see an alert with the ID.

Comment: It won't pop up. I don't know why. I tried in the fiddle and it worked.

Comment: Try using the standalone HTML I put at the end of my answer.

Comment: Yes! It worked! Thank you so much! I really really appreciated it! :D Lastly, If I were to change the first name tolowercase, do I just add the function after value?

Comment: Also, I have a submit button so if I click it will it save the id?

Comment: Yes, you can add .toLowerCase(): 

var fn = document.getElementById('Fname').value.toLowerCase();

Comment: Currently the resulting ID is only shown as a popup. 
You can show it into a text field to give user the chance to customize it (if that's something you want). 

If you don't want to show it to the user, you can save the generated ID into a hidden field. Though, this is not ideal: it is safer to compute the resulting ID in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function you need:

```
function generateID (firstName, lastName, id) 
{
    let fn = firstName.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    let ID = f[0].substr(0,1) + f[1].substr(0,1)+ lastName + id.toString().slice(-4);
    return ID;
}
```

Comment: It won't print anything. Do I have to add anything?